# compare the value of two cells on the same sheet Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to compare the value of two cells on the same sheet. If cell K6 is equal to cell G14, then do nothing, but if the value is different, then delete the content of these cells.

The function must be executed when editing the cell, so for this I make help of function onEdit()

This is my code:

```
function onEdit(){

  var libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var hojaOrigen = libro.getSheetByName('Añadir ficha');
  

  for (var i=buscador; i < columnH.length; i++){
    var buscador = hojaOrigen.getRange('K6').getValue();
    var nombre = hojaOrigen.getRange('G14').getValue();

    if (nombre == buscador) {
    } else {
      hojaOrigen.getRangeList(['G12', 'G14', 'C12', 'G16', 'K12', 'K14', 'K16', 'K18', 'G18', 'G20', 'K20','G22','K22','G24','K24','H26','K10','K28','G28']).clearContent();
    }
  }
}
```

Someone so kind to help me? All help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

EDIT:

I have managed to modify the code so that it works and does what I want, however now I find myself with the problem that the onEdit() function does not work. That is, when I change the value of cell K6, the function does not detect the change and the function is not activated.

On the other hand, if I create a trigger in the editor and tell it to execute this function when the sheet is edited, then if it is activated and it works.

So why do I want the onEdit() function? You could just name the function removeContent() ...

Also, with the trigger it takes more than 1 second to execute the onEdit() function. There is no way to reduce this time?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var hojaOrigen = libro.getSheetByName('Añadir ficha');      // Enter sheet name
  var buscador = hojaOrigen.getRange('K6');
  var nombre = hojaOrigen.getRange('G14');
  var value1 = buscador.getValue();
  var value2 = nombre.getValue();
  var borrarContenido = hojaOrigen.getRangeList(['G12', 'G14', 'C12', 'G16', 'K12', 'K14', 'K16', 'K18', 'G18', 'G20', 'K20','G22','K22','G24','K24','H26','K10','K28','G28']);

  Logger.log(value1);
  Logger.log(value2);
  Logger.log(borrarContenido);

  if (value1!=value2){  
  borrarContenido.clearContent();
}

if (value1==value2){ 
  ''
}
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your question. So, can I ask you about the detail of your current question?

Comment: Are you including anything else in the onEdit() function that is not shown in the question's snippet? Simple triggers "cannot access services that require authorization" (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions), so that might be the reason it works with an installable trigger, but not with a simple trigger.

Comment: Sometimes `onEdit()` doesn't work at first. I run it manually from Script Edtior. It gets an error, of course, but the function starts to work normally after that. Probably it's need additional permissions sometimes.

Comment: I'm not sure about the status of your problem now either. Do you have the original question solved? If you have a different question then its better to just post a new question from scratch.